# M2 | How to find referenceBlock name for the Sales Order View : Account Information Section?

Tags: magento2, blocks, containers, reference

Part1: I need to know the referenceBlock name for:

[image]

Part 2: and put a button at:
[image]

“If you have knowledge, let others light their candles in it.”
― Margaret Fuller

Answer (score 0):

Template File: **vendor/magento/module-sales/view/adminhtml/templates/order/view/info.phtml**

Template Notation : **Magento_Sales::order/view/info.phtml**

Layout File: **module-sales/view/adminhtml/layout/sales_order_view.xml**

ReferenceBlock Name: **order_info**

---

To add a button, you can create a custom module and in that module create the files:

sales_order_view.xml:

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="order_info" template="Vendor_Module::order/view/info.phtml" />
    </body>
</page>
```

And copy the template over to view/adminhtml/templates/order/view/info.phtml and make changes to that phtml file as needed. The part of the template file that corresponds to the row with the email is around line 140 (I slipped in a button to show you where it might go):

```
<tr>
    <th><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Email')) ?></th>
    <td><a href="mailto:<?php echo $block->escapeHtml($order->getCustomerEmail()) ?>"><?php echo $block->escapeHtml($order->getCustomerEmail()) ?></a><button>Click Me!</button></td>
```

Comment: Hi @Jorge, I know about this solution when I apply this get my output below order # 000000064 as in Screen shot 1. You can see written "This is form info.phtml". I need to put it in account information section. Can you test this solution.